# Error: 'Socket is not connected' when doing: 'socket.recv(1024)'

Tags: python, sockets

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = connexion.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import socket

connexion = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connexion.bind(('', 12800))
connexion.listen(5)

client, info = connexion.accept()

continuer = ""
while(continuer.upper() != "Q"):
    data = connexion.recv(1024) #I get the error here
    continuer = raw_input("")
else:
    connexion.close()
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem with my code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving from the connexion socket, instead of the client socket.

Each client socket is bound to another connection. But the server socket (connexion here) accepts client socket, it does not recv/send.

A quick fix to your code would be :

```
continuer = ""
while(continuer.upper() != "Q"):
    data = client.recv(1024)
    continuer = raw_input("")
else:
    client.close()
```

Besides, I'm not sure that the else will do something.
You should remove it as after your while condition is reached, your client socket will be closed anyway.

@Jeremy Friesner : Faster than me. But I post the answer anyway as it's more *complete*.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = connexion.recv(1024) #I get the error here
```

should be

```
data = client.recv(1024)
```